# Capturar evento al cerrar DIV

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces

Existe alguna forma de capturar en un evento cuando el DIV que está destacado se cierre? (en realidad cambia el display a none). Si yo hago click fuera del elemento este se cierra y necesito realizar algo cuando esto pasa. El elemento de Primefaces no tiene ningún evento asociado, y desconozco si por CSS JS tengo alguna forma de capturar esto.
- Estoy atento si se requiere más información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias capturar el evento click en el body y chequear si tu div es visible

Comment: Como bien dices, haces clic fuera y este div se cierra por lo tanto puedes capturar el evento `onFocusOut` [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp) y ahi tratar lo necesario

Answer (score 1):

puedes agregar un observer para monitorear los cambios en un nodo. El siguiente ejemplo es una modificación de este https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer lo modificas.

```
<body>
    <div id='my-div'>
        <p>este es mi div</p>
    </div>
    <button id='my-button' onclick="hide('my-div')">esconder</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hide(id){
            if(document.getElementById(id).style.display!='none'){
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
            }

        }
        var targetNode=document.getElementById('my-div');

        var config = { attributes: true, childList: false };

        var callback = function(mutationsList) {
            for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
                    if(mutation.attributeName=='style'){
                        if(targetNode.style.display=='none'){
                            console.log('el elemento se ocultó');
                            //acá va nuestra función
                        }else{
                            console.log('el elemento se hizo visible');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

        observer.observe(targetNode, config);

    </script>
</body>
```